# Convert IMA ADPCM WAV to Linear PCM inside app

Tags: android

Can anyone help me how to convert ADPCM WAV audio file to linear PCM, or how to at least play ADPCM in android?

Can this code be changed to play ADPCM Wav?
https://github.com/mitch000001/ringdroid/blob/master/src/com/ringdroid/soundfile/CheapWAV.java

Thank you.